# Having IntelliJ IDEA auto-download libraries from Maven

Tags: intellij-idea, dependencies

I've set up a Scala project in IntelliJ idea with several dependency libraries auto-downloaded by the IDE from Maven repositories, using the [built-in support for this functionality](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/downloading-libraries-from-maven-repositories.html). The libraries are then automatically downloaded into a local folder and everything works as expected.

My problem is when some of those libraries go missing- either because I've deleted them, or because I'm pulling the project from a clean machine and the library binaries aren't included in version control. I'd like to tell IDEA to automatically re-download all dependency libraries from the Maven repository; I know this is possible because all the necessary information can be found in the .iml file.

If I manually go to every library in the "Project Structure" dialogue and click "Edit," I can repeat the original workflow to redownload from Maven repo without touching any settings. This is inconvenient when there are many libraries, though. Is there any way to tell IDEA to just do this for me for all Maven repo libraries included in the project?

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to use Apache Maven and maintain a `pom` file with a list of all dependencies (with the possibility to keep it in source control, etc) which you can simply `reimport` whenever you need to. IntelliJ and Maven will then manage all your libraries for you, along with their javadocs and sources. There are many, many, other benefits from this approach -- it is highly recommended.

[image: Reimport screenshot]

Comment: is that answer still up to date?